# How to add a space before each tweet in css

Tags: css, twitter

http://cargocollective.com/joingateillustration

Hi everyone, this is my site I am developing and I have managed to add my twitter feed to my page however I cant add a line break before each tweet, Ive searched here and people have posted answers to a similar post but this doesnt seem to affect mine, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a top margin to your tweet list items:

```
#twitter_update_list li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
#twitter_update_list li span
{
   padding-top:10px;
}
```